# How to configure UISearchBar scope buttons to not trigger "search mode"?

Tags: ios

I think by default, UISearchDisplayController/UISearchController and/or UISearchBar uses an effect, when tapped, to animate the search bar into the navigation bar and display a darkened overlay on the table data. I have added scope buttons to my search bar, so I want to be able to tap one of the scope buttons to update the current table view rather than starting a new search (animating and darkening). How can this be done using the UISearchBar and scope buttons?

Comment: You should not be using UISearchDisplayController any more. Update to UISearchController. It's a lot better!

Comment: @matt Oh, I thought I already was. Let's assume that I will be using that. Does that change anything?